# Why is rawurldecode returning an empty string when decoding %D?

Tags: php

This is driving me crazy. I'd like to know why in this PHP example code:

```
$str = '<p>Delivery: %DELIVERY-STAMP%</p>';
$str = rawurldecode($str);
echo $str;
```

The result is an empty string. But in this:

```
$str = '<p>Delivery: % DELIVERY-STAMP%</p>';
$str = rawurldecode($str);
echo $str;
```

The result result is

```
&lt;p&gt;Delivery: % DELIVERY-STAMP%&lt;/p&gt;
```

The only difference is the extra space in % D. In other words, something really bad happens when the string "%D" is passed to rawurldecode() because I always get an empty string as result. This may be a bug? I couldn't find any reference regarding "%D" in the documentation. I'm using PHP 5.4.2 In the actual code I cannot avoid running rawurldecode(). Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The result of the first is NOT an empty string.

Comment: Well, I can assure you that the result IS an empty string, at least in my box (PHP 5.4.2, OSX). Maybe it has to do with the error reporting setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's interpreting `%DE` as a literal character and decodes it to some character (222). From [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php):

> Returns a string in which the sequences with percent (%) signs
> followed by two hex digits have been replaced with literal characters.

Well, `D` and `E` are valid hex digits, so, it gets replaced.

The real solution is to [pass your string to `rawurlencode()` first](http://viper-7.com/qre5R1), then you can decode it with `rawurldecode()`, since in order to decode something, it needs to be encoded properly.

```
$str = rawurlencode( '<p>Delivery: %DELIVERY-STAMP%</p>');
$str = rawurldecode($str);
echo $str;
```

The input string, properly encoded, looks like this:

```
%3Cp%3EDelivery%3A%20%25DELIVERY-STAMP%25%3C%2Fp%3E
```

Comment: Wait... so you're telling this person to encode a string and then decode the result of encoding the string? That's a no-op, what's the point of that?

Comment: It's so that URL characters like / can be passed. Look at google

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark here, but here's my best guess:

You are running the `$str` through `htmlspecialchars` without telling us about it. The reason I say this is because `rawurldecode("<")` will NOT give you `&lt;`. So, with that in mind, what does `rawurldecode` actually give? It gives this:

> <p>Delivery: ÞLIVERY-STAMP%</p>

It gives this because it sees `%DE` as a URL-encoded string and decodes it into `Latin Capital Letter Thorn`. Here's the catch, though. That character is outside the 0-127 range, and therefore has special meaning in UTF-8, which, by the way, is what `htmlspecialchars` defaults to in PHP 5.4.

As a direct result, you have "malformed UTF-8" (actually perfectly valid Windows-1252) and the result is an empty string.

I don't know why you're using `rawurldecode` in the first place since if you had an encoded string it wouldn't have `<` in the first place (rather `%3C`). So try this:

```
$str = '<p>Delivery: %DELIVERY-STAMP%</p>';
echo htmlspecialchars(utf8_encode($str));
```

OR

```
echo htmlspecialchars($str,ENT_COMPAT,"ISO-8859-1");
```

Comment: Sorry, but as you can see htmlspecialchars() is not in the example code, $str is just plain text...

Comment: But my explanation made sense... it even explained why you had `&lt;` in your output...